# Laravel & Typeahead.js: retrieve category name but submit its ID to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, typeahead.js

I managed to integrate Typeahead.js with my laravel app. But unfortunately, I need to submit its `ID` instead of its `name`. I need to retrieve the name of the category with Typeahead but insert its ID in the database because that's how I'm referencing it.

So far I am getting an sql error because it's expecting an integer but instead it's getting a string (name of the category).

I tried doing a `foreach` and assign `$result->id` to `$data[]` but that didn't work at all.

How can I fix that?

`getSubreddits` method in `PostsController`

```
public function getSubreddits($query) {
        $results = Subreddit::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
        return Response::json($results);
    }
```

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var subreddits = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: 'http://localhost/reddit/public/data/subreddits',
                remote: {
                    url: 'http://localhost/reddit/public/data/subreddits/%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'name',
                display: 'name',
                source: subreddits
            });
        });
</script>
```

Routes

```
Route::get('data/subreddits', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
Route::get('data/subreddits/{QUERY}', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
```

Entire `store()` method in `PostsController.php`

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
    {
        if (Input::has('link')) {
            $input['link'] = Input::get('link');
            $info = Embed::create($input['link']);

            if ($info->image == null) {
                $embed_data = ['text' => $info->description];
            } else if ($info->description == null) {
                $embed_data = ['text' => ''];
            } else {
                $extension = pathinfo($info->image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $newName = public_path() . '/images/' . str_random(8) . ".{$extension}";

                if (File::exists($newName)) {
                    $imageToken = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 5);
                    $newName = public_path() . '/images/' . str_random(8) . '-' . $imageToken . ".{$extension}";
                }

                $image = Image::make($info->image)->fit(70, 70)->save($newName);
                $embed_data = ['text' => $info->description, 'image' => basename($newName)];
            }

            Auth::user()->posts()->create(array_merge($request->all(), $embed_data));

            return redirect('/articles');
        }
        Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());

        return redirect('/');
}
```

And the form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
      <p>
         {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
         {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'title']) !!}
      </p>

      <p>
         {!! Form::label('link', 'Link:') !!}
         {!! Form::text('link', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'link']) !!}
      </p>

       <p>
          <div id="remote">
           <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Subreddit" name="subreddit_id">
          </div>
       </p>

        <p>
           {!! Form::submit('Submit Post', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
         </p>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: It should be `Subreddit::select('id')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();` Right?

Comment: No, that would break typeahead altogether and won't retrieve anything. However, `select('name', 'id')` will retrieve both the name and the id of the category, but how do I submit the ID to the database in the submit form?

Comment: You want to submit the `id` in the above statement?

Comment: No, I only want to pass the ID to the form, the `store` method handles the submitting to the database and it requires a subreddit_id not a subreddit_name

Comment: Can i see the 'sotre' method and the form?

Comment: It's a big function, but mainly this line is what submits data to the database `Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());`

Comment: `Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->id());`

Comment: No man, there are other input fields in the form, I can't just take the id field.

Comment: Then create another query.

Comment: Why would I do that? It's all working just fine. I just want to be able to grab the ID instead of the NAME in the `getSubreddits()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

```
<div id="remote">
    <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Subreddit" name="subreddit_name">
    <input type="hidden" id="subreddit_id" name="subreddit_id" value="">  
</div>
...
$('#remote .typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
            $('#subreddit_id').val(suggestion.id);
});
```